# Highlight Cell after 'X' minutes

Tags: excel, vba, timer, conditional-statements, highlight

Is it possible to Highlight a cell after x amount of minutes but if value has been entered into cell it will no longer highlight? is this possible to write in VBA or something simpler like conditional formatting?

so process im after is -> Cell value has been entered into B4, Enter, and in 5mins more or less, B5 will highlight a colour(maybe Red), but as soon as a value has been entered into B5, the highlight will disappear and restart that time again for cell B6 until value has been entered and so on

Range i need to add this is B4:B168. That range is in text format.

Im really bad at VBA and am slowly getting better at it by learning how to do all this, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to highlight a Microsoft Excel cell with Visual Basics after a certain amount of time according to the Official Microsoft Office Developers Center.

Here is the link if you want to look: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/Concepts/Cells-and-Ranges/highlight-the-active-cell-row-or-column

Hope this was helpful!